# Numerous axios calls on loop even if rules is set for vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js, axios

When ratio is selected, multidimensional loop is initiate. Everything works fine, however.. functions is also called based on order key name. This is where everything goes tricky and brakes.

`$parent[key]()` calls right function and tries to return json data. The strange thing which happens is that axios calling server numerous of times  (3000-4000 times till it brakes) on `$parent.item_set.ratio` change.

For testing purpose, i disabled all, except the one with `id === 0`.

```
<select v-model="$parent.item_set.ratio">
  <option disabled value="">Please select</option>
  <option v-for="(ratios, index) in $parent.items[$parent.item_set.item].mods[$parent.item_set.mod].options[$parent.item_set.option].ratios" :value="ratios.join(', ')">@{{ ratios.join(', ') }}</option>
</select>


<div v-if="$parent.item_set.ratio">
  <div v-for="(order, key, id) in $parent.items[$parent.item_set.item].mods[$parent.item_set.mod].orders">

    <div v-if="id === 0">
        <select v-model="$parent.item_set.orders[key]">
           <option disabled value="">Please select</option>
           <option v-for="(value, index) in $parent[key]()">@{{ value }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Axios**

```
function_key_name() {
  this.loader('function_key_name', 'random?query=data');
  return this.item_settings.function_key_name;
},


loader(a, b) {
  this.parts(a+'/'+b).then((json) => {
     this.item_settings[a] = json.data;
  }).catch(error => {
     // alert(error.response.data.message);
  });
}
```

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: I guess, the issue is that you've called the function inside `v-for` `$parent[key]()`

Comment: @varit05 this was my guess also, but even if i am not calling function in loop, but calling outside it gives me same issue.. :/ however.. if i am doing something similar, but with on:click it works

Comment: Is it possible to copy + paste code in codesandbox, so I can look into this?

Comment: @varit05 not really, because this is only one part of huge difficult code and logic. But this is the part, where it brakes.

Comment: @varit05 i managed to fix it. The issue was indeed with $parent[key](). Technically speaking, there is no issue with that at all, but the way how it must work was the issue. I managed to fix it by replacing that function call with basic $parent.settings[key] and initiating function call on previous index change event. This did the trick. Your comment was right, so if you could put that as answer, i would be able to accept as correct answer.

Comment: Glad to hear @Tauras ! I will put it in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the function call `$parent[key]()` on `v-for` loop.

It can be fix by replacing that function call with basic $parent.settings[key] and initiating function call on previous index change event.

```
<option v-for="(value, index) in $parent[key]">@{{ value }}</option>
```

Glad it worked!

Comment: Good spot, good man, thanks. But if you can, change asnwer with something what i wrote. This would be better.

Comment: Updated the answer! If you still think, you can edit the answer :)